# SICP Types and Variables

Tags: scheme, sicp

This is from the [MIT 6.001 Online Tutor](http://icampustutor.csail.mit.edu/6.001-public/tutor.cgi), it's part of the third problem set.

**Question: Indicate the type of each of the following expressions. If you need type variables, use A,B,C, etc., starting with A as the leftmost variable.**

1. `(lambda (x y) x)` = `A,B->A`
2. `(lambda (p) (p 3))`
3. `(lambda (p x) (p x))` = `(A->B), A->B`
4. `(lambda (x y comp) (if (comp x y) x y))`

As you can see I solved 1 and 3, but that was mainly out of luck. I still am having issues with understanding the concept and that is stopping me from solving 2 and 4.

Lecture slides can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://icampustutor.csail.mit.edu/6.001-public/courseexport/lessons/Lesson6/lecture6.pdf) (view the last few).

Comment: I'm actually having trouble understanding the question... aren't they all lambdas? How are their data types different in the first place?

Comment: Yes they are all lambdas which is why you have to use general A,B,C notation instead of things like number->number. The slides are here and it's the last couple slides that deal with this type of question. [link for slides](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Ficampustutor.csail.mit.edu%2F6.001-public%2Fcourseexport%2Flessons%2FLesson6%2Flecture6.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A, B -> A
2. (number -> A) -> A
3. (A -> B), A -> B
4. A, A, (A, A -> boolean) -> A

(the last assumes that `x` and `y` are the same types)